# VGA monitor as the display for VHS player

Tags: lcd, vga

How do I connect an LCD monitor to be the display for a VHS VCR?

Answer (score 6):

If your VCR has RCA video out you will need an [RCA to VGA (d-sub) converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000V58F9M).

I never tried these but there are many out there. Depending on your budget and video quality needed.

Answer (score 4):

There are any number of video to VGA converters like [these](http://www.ramelectronics.net/audio-video/audio-video-computer/video-to-vga/c10000-c11300-c11302-p1.html). Google around and you can find more. Prices vary widely and I don't have any direct experience to recommend one over another.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need a TV Tuner card, because monitors are designed for a higher refresh rate so the picture would have to be digitized. The bonus though is that you would get to also watch tv on it. I picked one up on eBay for about $15 and I set it to record all my shows as a DVR.

If your monitor has composite cables on it, you could hook it up through those, but the pic quality is not going to be so great coming off VHS.

Comment: Your first paragraph assumes OP connects a PC between the monitor and the VCR.  Should work, though.